# Using Reagent in sbt

Tags: playframework, sbt, clojurescript, reagent

Some time ago i used the [reagent](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent) library and was very pleased with it features and speed.

But now i'm involved in some web development with [play framework](https://www.playframework.com/) and sseking opportunity to use this nice library in my project.

There is a [clojurescript compile plugin](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/play-clojurescript) for play, so i suppose it could be used to compile and maybe concatenate & minimize reagent assets.

So question is: could reagent be used without leiningen on top of sbt build?

**UPDATE:**
 I have googled [this successor of clojurescript plugin](https://github.com/petro-rudenko/play-clojurescript).

From description of plugin and [this issue (by the author of the successor lib)](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/play-clojurescript/issue/1/third-party-clojurescript-libraries)  i've learned that depencies and resolver should be declared in `plugins.sbt`

i've added this code on `plugins.sbt` afterwards:

```
addSbtPlugin("io.github.petro-rudenko" % "play-clojurescript" % "0.0.2")

resolvers += "clojars" at "http://clojars.org/repo/"

resolvers += "clojure-releases" at "http://build.clojure.org/releases"

libraryDependencies += "reagent" % "reagent" % "0.5.0"
```

and write sample cljs

```
(ns javascripts.reagentsample
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent]))

(enable-console-print!)

(defn input-field [label-text id]
  (let [value (atom nil)]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:label "The value is: " @value]
       [:input {:type      "text"
                :value     @value
                :on-change #(reset! value (-> % .-target .-value))}]])))

(reagent/render-component [input-field] (.-body js/document))
```

Code have been compiled and concatenated with clojurescript core and reagent library. After some removement of requirejs and angular cloacks all became magically working.

So right now i have only one issue: i could not require my own namespace. Despite all attempts in naming i gain `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such namespace:` during clojurescript compilation.

From perspective of [that source](https://github.com/petro-rudenko/play-clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/scala/assets/compiler/cljs/ClojurescriptPlugin.scala) i could say that entry point of clojurescript compuler in my project is `app/assets/` so my main file have following namespace definition :

```
(ns javascripts.reagentsample
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]
            [javascripts.lol :refer [mystring]]))
```

And my secondary source have that definition:

```
(ns javascripts.lol)
```

Both are located in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder.

Comment: I don't know enough about the tools involved to know for sure, but have you tried just adding the Clojars repository to your build.sbt and going for it?

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided doesn't say anything about Clojurescript libraries, but this one does: https://github.com/petro-rudenko/play-clojurescript. I think that should do what your looking for.

Comment: Yes. I've used that plugin. Let me update the question to provide more info on current state